# Create a PyObject with attached functions and return to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyobject

I wonder how I can create a `PyObject` in C++ and then return it to Python.

Sadly the documentation is not very explicit about it.
There is no `PyObject_Create` so I wonder whether allocating `sizeof(PyObject)` via `PyObject_Malloc` and initializing the struct is sufficient.

For now I only need an object with functions attached.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want a (1) `PyObject`, as in what Python calls `object`, or (2) *an object* of some subtype? That you "need an object with functions attached" seems to indicate you want either methods or attributes. That needs (2) in any case. I'm no expert on the C API, but generally you'd define your own `PyTypeObject`, then create an instance of that via `PyObject_New` (refcount and type field are initialized, other fields you might add are not).